# how to use systemctl cmd in docker container?

Tags: docker, odoo

in my case,i want use systemctl command in docker, how do I do it?

I have modified /var/lib/docker/containers/60f58068d1514a5ba36bf4fa6ce1c14807102c2fa1a961d56aa1a47f38157a96/config.v2.json cmd and path option to /sbin/init but it didn't work

Comment: A docker container usually wraps a single process, so there's no need to run things as daemons. Can you explain what you're trying to achieve in more detail?

Comment: ...and if you do have a multi-process container, it's also unusual to run systemd as the process supervisor; systemd wants to control a _lot_ of things that aren't accessible in the container environment.  Normally you'd run the one process in the foreground as the main container `CMD`, and run multiple containers if you need multiple processes.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.